# Python and shell script

Tags: python, excel, shell

Need a python script that reads data from a Excel sheet . 
It passes the parameters read from Excel sheet to a shell script to download a file from server.
It also updates a column in  the Excel sheet with Y or N . (The Excel sheet contains the server details and the file which needs to be downloaded.
Ex :filename | directory | server | y/n )

Comment: Please read this and edit your question accordingly https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with Excel files is definitely something people care about. I love the following author who wrote a book on how to use Python in everyday life:
https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter12/

This chapter in particular deals with Python and Excel. He describes how to use the package `openpyxl`. You should be able to read and edit the Excel file with that package.

As for ftp, maybe you can just use ftp for that? :) Otherwise, there are many python packages for dealing with ftp. I’m using `urllib.request` right now for accessing webpages.